# Ruby on Rails API that functions similar to WCF does on ASP.NET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wcf, api

Is there an API similar to WCF for Ruby on Rails? 
WCF has a lot of advantages and is a very easy method to have a service running and clients using it.
I want to know if there is an API similar to WCF for the Ruby on Rails platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails uses [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) web services by default, and you can easily generate routes and controller actions for these "out of the box".  Like WCF, Rails supports both JSON and XML formats for data transfer.

If you need to support SOAP, there are Rails ad-ons, such as [savon](http://savonrb.com/).

ian.